# Reach a subnet using a specific network device

Tags: networking, network-interface, ip, routing, vpn

My setup is the following:

### Local network

- `192.168.1.1/16`: FritzBox 7530 as Router/Modem
- `192.168.1.100/16`: my dev machine (Ubuntu 20.04)

The FritzBox creates a VPN tunnel to connect a remote machine over the Internet.

### Remote network

- `192.168.0.254/16`: remote router/modem
- `192.168.0.10/16`: eth0 address of my remote machine (Ubuntu 20.04)
- `192.168.1.200/24`: tun0 address (assigned by my FrtizBox) of my remote machine after VPN connection
- `192.168.1.30/16`: target device I want to connect to

### What works

If I disable the VPN connection (tun0) and I remotely log in to my machine (192.168.0.10/16) using a VNC software I can reach the target device (192.168.1.30/16) because (I guess) both have the same netmask.

### What does NOT work

If I enable the VPN connection, from my local machine (192.168.1.100/16) I **cannot** reach the target device (192.168.1.30/16) through tun0 (192.168.1.200/24) because this one has a wrong netmask.

Unfortunately I haven't understood how to change the netmask of a VPN connection in the FritzBox yet.

On the remote machine (192.168.1.200/24) this is the routing table:

```
$ ip r
default dev tun0 proto static scope link metric 50 
default via 192.168.0.254 dev enp2s0 proto dhcp metric 100 
<public ip> via 192.168.0.254 dev enp2s0 proto static metric 100 
192.168.0.0/16 dev enp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.10 metric 100 
192.168.0.254 dev enp2s0 proto static scope link metric 100 
192.168.1.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.200 metric 50
```

### Question

Is it possible to create a rule that allows me to reach the target device (192.168.1.30/16) from my local dev machine (192.168.1.100/16) through the tun0 on the remote machine (192.168.1.200/24) via the eth0 interface (192.168.0.10/16) ?

In this way it should work because the two legs are both valid:

- leg 1: local dev machine (192.168.1.100/16)  <--->  remote tun0 (192.168.1.200/24)
- leg 2: remote eth0 (192.168.0.10/16)  <--->  target device (192.168.1.30/16)

Please note I don't have a physical access to the remote machine, so I must be careful when changing the network settings otherwise I cannot login anymore!

Comment: Your local network and your remote network are the same network.  192.168.1.0/16 includes 192.168.anything.anything.

Comment: @JimL. please, read carefully the setup. Because the local and remote networks are connected via `tun0` the local network "sees" the remote one through a netmask /24. In fact, I cannot reach any server on 192.168.1.x in the remote network *from* the local one. While, of course, both local and remote machines can reach those addresses directly.

Comment: I'd suggest getting the tunnel re-configured to tunnel the entire /16, so that once you're linked via the tunnel, you can hit any box that FritzBox has the ability to reach.  You may want to look into "proxy arp." It's likely that FritzBox will need to proxy your machine's IP with FritzBox's MAC address so that clients on the LAN local to FritzBox will know to send traffic for your machine (192.168.1.100) to FritzBox.  FritzBox should then forward it over the tunnel, etc.

Comment: @JimL. that makes sense, but the whole manual of FritzBox (284 pages) has no hits for arp or proxy... I'm afraid it does not support this feature.

Comment: The simplest solution is to change the netmask of `tun0` (assigned by the FritzBox), but I don't not how to do this.